# SPOJ The next Palindrome ( Java)

Tags: java, palindrome

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long n,a;
        boolean b;

        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            n = sc.nextLong();

            for ( long i = 0; i<n; i++){
                a = sc.nextLong();
                for ( long j = (a+1); j<1000000000; j++){
                    b = isPalindrome(j);
                    if ( b == true){
                        System.out.println(j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception e){
            return;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(long n){
        String intStr = String.valueOf(n); 
        return intStr.equals(new StringBuilder(intStr).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with my Palindrome code? 
In SPOJ, the first two test cases are compiling but for the next one and onwards it's showing the wrong answer.

First test case:
2
808
2133

output:
818
2222

Comment: Run your code under debugger step-by-step and check all relevant variables.

Comment: @PM77-1 I runned code on Onlinegdb and Ideone, I get correct ans. But when I submit in SPOJ it showsss wrong.

Comment: Have you run "failing" cases outside of SPOJ?

Comment: @PM77-1 there are not mentioned other test cases.

Comment: Can you link to SPOJ problem ?

Comment: @Benoit https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

Comment: `long` can hold values up to 2^64 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807), so you shouldn't be getting any "out of range" problems here

Comment: It says: "For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 **digits**".  So the largest value of K will be represented by a string of  1000000 "9"s.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that neither `int` neither `long` are big enough to store *a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits* - **1000000 digits** is well 10<sup>1000000</sup>, while `Long.MAX_VALUE` is only 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

Thus you have to use **BigInteger**.

The following code seems to work (no more `NZEC`), but it ends up with `time limit exceeded`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(readLine()).add(BigInteger.ONE);
            if (a.signum() == -1) {
                a = BigInteger.ZERO;
            }
            while (a.toString().length() <= 1000000) {
                if (isPalindrome(a.toString())) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                    break;
                }
                a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String intStr) {
        int l = intStr.length();
        for (int i=0, j=l-1; i < l/2+1; i++, j--) {
            if (intStr.charAt(i) != intStr.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static String readLine() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @VaibhavA On which line ?

Comment: int n = Integer.parseInt(readLine());     &      BigInteger a = new BigInteger(readLine()).add(BigInteger.ONE);

Comment: Same problem Time Limit Exceeded

Comment: (See my updated answer) OK I guess they test limit condition,probably causing infinite loop. I added an exit condition in my loop. I will test it on SPOC later.